# C: integers not printing correctly

Tags: c

(Hi guys. I tried searching for the problem I'm having and can't seem to find the solution so far. I'm totally new to programming and am learning C currently, but I am a complete noob so I apologize in advance if I'm making a dumb mistake.)

Here's the problem: Im tryna scan 4 integers and print their values using a while loop. The problem is, the numbers are being printed as crazy long numbers not as the ints that are input. I tried scanning and printing a single int and it printed fine but once I use multiple ints, it starts screwing aroud.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, n1,n2,n3,n4;
    printf("Enter 4 numbers.");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("\n\nEnter number %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d", &n1,&n2,&n3,&n4);
        printf("%d,%d,%d,%d", n1,n2,n3,n4);
    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to test the result of `scanf` (the count of scanned items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping 4 times, expecting to read 4 numbers in each loop...

Generally speaking, `scanf()` is a poor tool for parsing any kind of input that *might* not match the expected format -- and nothing is as fickle as user input. I usually advise reading in whole lines of input (via `fgets()`), and then parsing them in-memory as appropriate (which, in this case, would probably mean using `strtol()` and checking how much of the input string was parsed via its second parameter).

This, for example, is **much** more robust:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define LINELEN_MAX 100

int main()
{
    int i;
    char input[ LINELEN_MAX ];
    char * current;
    char * end;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        // whitespaces or commas do not matter,
        // and neither does the amount of numbers.
        puts( "Enter numbers, or 'q' to quit." );

        if ( fgets( input, LINELEN_MAX, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            puts( "Error on read." );
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if ( *input == 'q' )
        {
            puts( "Quitting." );
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        if ( input[ strlen( input ) - 1 ] != '\n' )
        {
            puts( "Line exceeded maximum width." );
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        current = input;
        end = input;

        while ( *current )
        {
            if ( !isdigit( *current ) )
            {
                // skip non-digits
                ++current;
            }
            else
            {
                // parse 1..n digits and print
                printf( "%ld\n", strtol( current, &end, 10 ) );
                current = end;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. the input *format* given in `scanf()` should match exactly to the input *value* for a successful *scan*. [You need to have `,`s in your input]
2. Always check for the success of `scanf()` to ensure proper scanning of value. `scanf()` returns the number of items successfully matched and scanned.

So, you should change your code to something like,

```
 if ( scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d", &n1,&n2,&n3,&n4) == 4)
 {
       // use n1, n2, n3, n4
 }
 else
   //don't use them, return some error.
```

Note: Always initialize local variables. Many a time it will save you from the undefined behaviour of *read-before-write* scenario.

Also, [maybe?] the `for` loop is not required, as you're scanning *all the four* numbers at a time.

Comment: @grammer Sorry, i din't get you. I just mentioned what you need to do. What else you want to know? Did i miss something?

Comment: @SouravGhosh *Two things* but 1., 2., 3. :D?

Comment: @Rizier123 ___note___ -d, sir, :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you have `scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d", &n1,&n2,&n3,&n4);`

you must give your input as say
`1,2,3,4`( `commas` are needed)

And you said you want to read 4 numbers and you have a `scanf` that gets the 4 numbers. So there is no need for a loop here. If you want to loop get `one number` each time inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

One reason may be that all your values are being printed onto the same line without any space between them.

Basically you are printing 4 numbers continuously in one line which makes it look like one big number.

I advise you to add a new line format specifier.(If you are a newbie, then you might not understand this, so here are some links that may be useful)

http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output

There is also the problem that you are reading 4 numbers 4 times , that is you are reading 16 variables in total. For this code , you actually don't need a for loop.